# Ant problem when building rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I following the instructions on the rosjava welcome page http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/wiki/Welcome.

Everything goes fine until I try to build rosjava.jar.

At first, the result of the "ant dist" instruction was that it was unable to find the sdk.dir folder, so I decided to hardcode the path of my Android sdk installation. If I write the command "android" in the shell, I can see how the AVD manager starts.

Now, the problem is that the build fails because it's unable to find com.android.ant.SetupTask

See the error trace below:

```
BUILD FAILED
/myfolder/rosjava/rosjava/build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/myfolder/rosjava/rosjava/build-common.xml:16: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/myfolder/rosjava/rosjava/dependencies.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/myfolder/rosjava/rosjava/android/build.xml:6: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/myfolder/rosjava/rosjava/android/library/build.xml:38: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/myfolder/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/pre_setup.xml:13: taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

Someone asked if I have the anttasks.jar under the /myfolder/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib folder, and yes, I do.

What can be happening?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10179/ant-problem-when-building-rosjava/) by [Oryonym](https://answers.ros.org/users/649/oryonym/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-07**:
what do you mean by 'hardcode the path of my Android sdk installation'? The only setup I did was to add the Android SDK to my path.  For the rest, I use the "android update project --path .' to generate the local.properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Possibly this?

http://blog.klacansky.com/matter-code/ant-taskdef-class-com-android-ant-setuptask-cannot-be-found

Or this? (search for "SetupTask")

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494774/Getting-started-with-Android-PhoneGap-in-Eclipse

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1